# Video is not playing automatically in React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, video

Hy, I want to play videos automatically without controls. because I'm using it as a website banner background. Please point out what I have done wrong. I'm using chrome browser.

```
  <video
          autoPlay
          // playsinline
          autoplay
          muted
          loop
          className="stakingNft"
        >
        <source src="\assets\video\landing.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  
  </video>

--------------------------------

  <video
          autoPlay
          playsinline
          autoplay
          muted
          loop
          className="stakingNft"
        >
        <source src="\assets\video\landing.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  
  </video>
```

Comment: One time you write `autoPlay` and one time `autoplay`, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-archimedes-imdure?file=/src/App.js)

autoPlay might be defined twice and in small case that's the reason I think.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's issue in path of video.
You used backward slash instead of forward slash.

Here is the reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xbfng5?file=src%2FApp.js

---